# How to allow style attributes in HTML Purifier filtering

Tags: htmlpurifier

I'm having trouble with HTMLPurifier removing my style tags. This is the (test) configuration I use:

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('Core.Encoding', 'UTF-8'); // replace with your encoding
$config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'HTML 4.01 Transitional'); // replace with your doctype
$config->set('Cache.DefinitionImpl', null);
$config->set('HTML.AllowedElements','div');
$config->set('HTML.AllowedAttributes', "*.style");
$config->set('CSS.AllowedProperties', 'background-color');
```

And when I filter this HTML:

```
<div style="background-color: #fff;">test</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid #000;">test</div>
```

This is what I get:

```
<div>test</div>
<div style="border:;">test</div>
```

I don't understand why the border attribute is left (but it's value is stripped), and why the background-color attribute is removed. How do I configure so that those style tags are allowed through the filter? Also, I want to allow any style values for the style attributes that I allow.

Comment: Does it remove even if you comment out your configuration?

Comment: I apologize - after some more hours of troubleshooting I found the error and it was unrelated to HTML Purifier. Once I fixed it, the config settings worked as expected. Thanks for a great library.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('Core.Encoding', 'UTF-8'); // replace with your encoding
$config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'HTML 4.01 Transitional');
$config->set('CSS.Trusted', 'HTML 4.01 Transitional'); // allow any css
$config->set('HTML.Allowed','div[style]');
$config->set('CSS.AllowedProperties', 'background-color');
```

This works for me!